# How can I fix my code for an Arduino LED string controller?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm getting :
`invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript`
when I try to compile my code for my Arduino and for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Here's my code (feel free to use it although it isn't done yet).

```
/*
 * Changelog 0.5
 * pins[], pinFV[], pinV[], pinDelay[] moved
 * to pins[][]
 */
int analogPins[6] = {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5};
int pins[4][4];
int mode = 0;
void setup() {
  int x = 6;
  do {
    pinMode(analogPins[x], INPUT);
    x--;
  } while (x > 0);
  int pins[4] = {9, 5, 6, 3};
  x = 4;
  do {
    pinMode(pins[0][x], INPUT);
    x--;
  } while (x > 0);
  x = 4;
  do{
    pins[1][x] = random(5, 10);
    x--;
    }while(x>0);
  x = 4;
  do{
    pins[2][x] = random(50, 75);
    x--;
    }while(x>0);
  x = 4;
  do{
    pins[3][x] = 255;
    x--;
    }while(x>0);
 //this is the section causing the problem
  pins[0][0] = 8;
  pins[0][1] = 9;
  pins[0][2] = 10;
  pins[0][3] = 11;
//end section
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(19200);
}
void readAnalogDecode() {
  //analogAverage(pin);
  //elseIf statements to set what mode to use
  //catch anything out of bounds for mode select
  if (analogRead(A5) > 800 || analogRead(A5) < 0) {
    mode = 0;
  }
  if (analogRead(A5) > 4 && analogRead(A5) < 8) {
    mode = 0;
  }
  if (analogRead(A5) > 8 && analogRead(A5) < 15) {
    mode = 1;
  }
  if (analogRead(A5) > 15 && analogRead(A5) < 20) {
    mode = 2;
  }
  if (analogRead(A5) > 20 && analogRead(A5) < 26) {
    mode = 3;
  }
  if (analogRead(A5) > 26 && analogRead(A5) < 47) {
    mode = 4;
  }
  if (analogRead(A5) > 47 && analogRead(A5) < 185) {
    mode = 5;
  }
  if (analogRead(A5) > 185 && analogRead(A5) < 345) {
    mode = 6;
  }
}

void pinFader(int pin, int value) {
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);

  if (pins[3][pin] < value) {
    do {
      pins[3][pin] = pins[3][pin] + pins[1][pin];
      if (pins[3][pin] > 255) {
        pins[3][pin] = 255;
      }
      Serial.println(analogRead(A5));
      Serial.println(" ");
      Serial.println(analogRead(A4));
      analogWrite(pins[0][pin], pins[3][pin]);
      digitalWrite(8, LOW);
      delay(pins[2][pin]);
    } while (pins[3][pin] < value);
  }
  if (pins[3][pin] > value) {
    do {
      pins[3][pin] = pins[3][pin] - pins[1][pin];
      if (pins[3][pin] < 0 ) {
        pins[3][pin] = 0;
      }
      digitalWrite(8, LOW);
      analogWrite(pins[0][pin], pins[3][pin]);
      delay(pins[2][pin]);
    } while (pins[3][pin] > value);
  }
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println(" " );
  Serial.print(analogRead(A0));
  Serial.print(" " );
  Serial.print(analogRead(A1));
  Serial.print(" " );
  Serial.print(analogRead(A2));
  Serial.print(" " );
  Serial.print(analogRead(A3));
  Serial.print(" " );
  Serial.print(analogRead(A4));
  Serial.print(" " );
  Serial.print(analogRead(A5));
  Serial.print(" " );
  Serial.print(mode);
  readAnalogDecode();

  if (mode == 0) {
    pinFader(1, 255); //no green
    pinFader(2, 255); //no red
    pinFader(1, 0); //green on
    pinFader(3, 255); //no blue
    pinFader(2, 0);   //red on
    pinFader(1, 255); //no green
    pinFader(3, 0);   //blue on
    pinFader(1, 0);   //green on
    readAnalogDecode();}
  if (mode == 1) {
    analogWrite(9, 0);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(9, 255);
    /* delay(500);
      analogWrite(10, 0);
      delay(500);
      analogWrite(10, 255);
      delay(500);
      analogWrite(11, 0);
      delay(500);
      analogWrite(11, 255);
    */delay(500);
    readAnalogDecode();
  }
}
```

Is this not how to assign a value to a 2-d array? `pins[0][0] = 8;`
I apologize in advance if the problem is related to syntax. I'm used to java and python.

Comment: You have 2 arrays named pins.  You have one at global scope that is a 2D array.  You have it shadowed with another inside of loop that is a 4 element 1D array.  When you refer to pins inside of setup it is going to refer to the one at local scope, not the 2D array out at global scope.  In general it's best not to have two variables in the same scope with the same name.  It just gets confusing.

Comment: In `setup()`, you are accessing arrays out of bounds. When your array has 4 elements, then you must use index values 3, 2, 1, 0 to access the elements, but you use 4, 3, 2, 1. I did not read your code any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 arrays with the same name.  Inside setup the local one is the one that is referred to and it isn't a 2D array so you can't use it as such.

At global scope:

```
int pins[4][4];
```

And inside setup:

```
int pins[4] = {9, 5, 6, 3};
```

Try naming one of them something different.  Having two things with the same name can be terribly confusing.

Comment: Now I feel silly. That turns out to be that I just missed a line I needed to delete. Thank you and sorry for making such a simple mistake.

Comment: Usually, a 2D array is wrong. Or at least a questionable design. Usually, rows are very different from columns, so you either deal with an array of columns or an array or rows, (one dimension) but not with an unstructured 2D-array.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you mean by "unstructured". In order to have 2-d array, or more dimensions for that matter, you'd have to have a structure for it. Can you elaborate on that @datafiddler?

Comment: No idea what F, FV means, but obviously you have 4 objects with a `struct {int pin; int F; int FV ; int delay;}` pin (number) and delay are obviously very different, and `int` is the wrong type for both, eventually even for all 4 struct elements.